# How to get cookie from http login response in angular 11?

Tags: angular, angular8, angular11

I have **aws** login authentication ,I have sent cookie but after login successful i am not able to get cookie in angular 11 application. How can I get cookie? Please help .

Comment: Can you share some code? How are you adding cookie in the response?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create and read a value from cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie)